# How does ScanFilter based on MAC addresses work?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

The [ScanFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.html) android man page mentions that you can do filtering based on MAC addresses of remote devices ***"Current filtering on the following fields are supported: Mac address of the remote device."***. AFAIK, the address broadcasted in the advertisement is a "Private Resolvable Address" which is an address that changes periodically in order to avoid device tracking attacks. So, how does a ScanFilter know about the mac address of the remote device to do the filter. I've added the Bluetooth mac address for a remote device as a filter as in the following code snippet but scanning did not yield any results:

```
List<ScanFilter> listFilter = new ArrayList<>();
ScanFilter scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("88:88:88:B0:03:DB").build();
listFilter.add(scanFilterMac);
bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listFilter, scanSettings, scanCallback);
```

However, when I scan for a service based on UUID as in the following code snippet, the filtering works:

```
 List<ScanFilter> listFilter = new ArrayList<>();
 ScanFilter scanFilterService = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(SERVICE_ID).build();
 listFilter.add(scanFilterService);
 bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listFilter, scanSettings, scanCallback);
```

Any idea how to make ScanFilter based on remote device MAC address work? Is the MAC address mentioned in the man page is the same Bluetooth MAC address that you can get programmatically print on the other device using the following code:

```
 BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
 BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
 Log.i(TAG, "MAC: "+bluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

The addresses you can get when you scan devices are the mac addresses of BT devices which do not change. In the filtering you use this same address which is in format 12:34:56:78:9A:BC.
Your code:

```
ScanFilter scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("88:88:88:B0:03:DB")
```

is correct.

Most likely the problem you are facing that the filtered scan is not giving any result is because there is a bug in certain Android devices where the MAC address filtering does not work. I don't know exactly how many percentage of Android devices do not work since I have only access to about 10 different device models. If you want to verify that your code works I recommend using any Nexus device with latest firmware update.

### Summary

I recommend to not use this mac address filtering and make the filtering code yourself on onScanResult function to support all Android 5.0+ devices.